# Sample Java array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

Please help me with this Java array question:

The following code is designed to set `index` to the location of the first occurrence of target in the array `a`, and to set `index` to -1 if `target` is not found in `a`.

```
index = 0;
while(a[index] !=target){
    index++;
}
if(a[index] !=target){
    index = -1;
}
```

Which of the following describes the condition under which this program segment will fail to perform the task described?

A) Whenever `target` is the first element of the array

B) Whenever `target` is the last element of the array

C) Whenever `target` is not present in the array

D) Whenever `target` is -1

E) Whenever `target` = `a[target]`

Comment: What is `a` an array of?

Comment: C) Whenever target is not present in the array you will get ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The program will fail when `target` is not in the array due to `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and here's why.

Let's say the array looks like this, {1, 2, 3}. Three elements where

```
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
and a[2] = 3
```

Suppose `target` was 4. The loop would go through every element of the array and after comparing the last element to `target`, `index` will be incremented to 3 after checking that the last element `a[2]` doesn't equal 4.

However, this will cause an error in the while loop because it tries to access `a[3]` on the next iteration which is illegal since the bounds of a 3 element array only go from 0 to 2.

```
First iteration of loop:
a[0] != target
index = 1
Second iteration of loop:
a[1] != target
index = 2
Third iteration of loop
a[2] != target
index = 3
Fourth iteration of loop
a[3] != target <- this line cause an indexoutofboundsexception
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, when target is found the flag becomes true and the loop breaks giving you the value of index. And if flag is false the index is -1.

```
  boolean flag=false;
for(index=0;index<a.length;index++)
    {
      if(a[index]==target)
      {
        found=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  if(!found)
  index=-1;
```